# How can i return more then one string at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new to python and programming at all
Was trying to make a code to give me all the factors of a number, but can't see where i'm lacking

```
def divisores(numero):
  divisor = 0
  while divisor < numero :
    divisor += 1
    if numero % divisor == 0:
      return(divisor)

  
divisores(50)
```

all it shows is "1", that is the first factor. If i use "print", it indeed gives all the factors,but i wanted it to be all in a single line

Comment: The idea here is that you want to return multiple values, so a list or a set is the appropriate data structure. Alternatively you could choose to _yield_ your divisors, and that way they will only be calculated on-demand, which can be useful if you want to iterate over them individually.

Answer (score 1):

Return a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp):

```
def divisores(numero):
  divisor = 0
  divs = [] # empty list
  while divisor <= numero :
    divisor += 1
    if numero % divisor == 0:
      divs.append(divisor)
  return divs
```

Also, since you are counting `1` as an divisor, you likely want `numero` counting as a valid divisor as well. Hence, `while divisor <= numero`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output on a single line then you can achieve this conveniently by writing a generator which you unpack as follows:

```
def factors(n):
    def y(f):
        nonlocal neg
        yield f
        if neg:
            yield -f
    if n == 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot factor zero')
    if neg := n < 0:
        n = -n
    yield from y(1)
    for factor in range(2, n // 2 + 1):
        if n % factor == 0:
            yield from y(factor)
    yield from y(n)

print(*factors(50))
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 5 10 25
```